# Azure Service bus queue - Message proccessed vs active message proccessed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a webjob (App service) that acts on messages from a queue in Azure. I like to scale the webjob when I have a long queue. How do I do that?

From the criteria, I can see 2 options:
- Messages processed/Instance (AVG)
- Active Messages Processed/Instance (AVG)

However,I don't think they are relevant what so ever. Am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Service Bus queue/subscription can contain messages with several statuses: Active, Deferred, and Scheduled. Active messages processed would be for the messages that were with an Active state. I.e. messages that were not deferred or scheduled. Messages Processed metric would include messages with any state. The [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#message-metrics) metric names are not the same as the ones you see, though I get a feeling that's a UI discrepancy.

Comment: I also raised an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39950) to clarify in the document (perhaps it's stale) or align with AppService on the name. In case these are new metrics, the official ASB document should reflect those as well.